tried creating a Series of nan but getting "object of type float"
I'm trying to create a new variable in a dataframe that requires some complex conditional logic. I'd like the default value to be np.nan if all of the conditions fail.
my approach has been like this:
startingdf['name_of_new_variable'] = pd.Series(
    pd.nan,
    index=startingdf.index
).case_when(
    caselist=[
        (...,...),
        (...,...),
        (...,...),
        #etc etc
    ]
)

The key thing I'm hoping for here is that case_when will be called on a series populated with pd.nan (hence pd.Series(pd.nan...)).  That way there will be an automatic pd.nan in any row in the name_of_new_variable column where none of the conditions in the caselist are met.
But there's something wrong with pd.Series(pd.nan, index=startingdf.index).  When I write...
pd.Series(pd.nan, index=startingdf.index).case_when()

my typechecker (happens to be Pylance) complains that "object of type float is not callable."
So somehow, pd.Series(pd.nan, index=startingdf.index).case_when is returning a float instead of the (callable!) method case_when of a Series instance!
What am I doing wrong?

Please add detail as to your cases

Pandas doesn't have a nan attribute. Did you mean np.nan or pd.NA?

Series.case_when is new in 2.2, if anyone else wasn't aware.
